# Почему не грузится библиотека медиафайлов, не загружается фото в пост?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

**Суть проблемы:**
Поднял сайт из почти годовалого бэкапа загружаю а там каша, куча ошибок.
Исправил все кроме последнего, фотографии не загружаются и не цепляются на новые посты. Определил место ошибки это из-за темы, но что именно не понятно.

Прошу помощи, пожалуйста подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Вот что выводит `wp_debug` в админке:

> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Ads_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Ads125_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Feedburner_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Recent_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Popular_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Random_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Video_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Tabs_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Counter_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Ads_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Slider_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Headlines_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Posts_Varian1_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Posts_Varian2_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Posts_Varian3_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Posts_Varian4_Builder is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
>   __construct() instead. in /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3903
>
> Notice: add_object_page is deprecated since version 4.5.0! Use
>   add_menu_page() instead. in
>   /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3840
>
> Notice: get_currentuserinfo is deprecated since version 4.5.0! Use
>   wp_get_current_user() instead. in
>   /home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   3840
>
> Вот что выводит wp_debug на фронте:
>
> **Notice**:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in
>   SuperNews_Ads_Widget is **deprecated** since version
>   4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Ads125_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Feedburner_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Recent_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Popular_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Random_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Video_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Tabs_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Counter_Widget is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Ads_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Slider_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Headlines_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Posts_Varian1_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Posts_Varian2_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Posts_Varian3_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Notice**:  The called
>   constructor method for WP_Widget in SuperNews_Posts_Varian4_Builder is
>   **deprecated** since version 4.3.0! Use
>
> ```
> __construct()
> ```
>
> instead. in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **3903**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Parameter 2 to
>   qtranxf_excludeUntranslatedPosts() expected to be a reference, value
>   given in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php**
>   on line **286**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Parameter 2 to
>   qtranxf_postsFilter() expected to be a reference, value given in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php**
>   on line **286**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Parameter 2 to
>   qtranxf_excludeUntranslatedPosts() expected to be a reference, value
>   given in
>   **/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php**
>   on line **286**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Parameter 2 to
>   qtranxf_postsFilter() expected to be a referenc

Answer (score 0):

Указанные в вопросе сообщения не могут привести к полной неработоспособности сайта, это всего лишь Notice и Warning, да и относятся они к виджету Super News и плагину переводов qtranslate.

Предположу, что при восстановлении сайта из бэкапа изменился путь к файлам (раньше был не `/home/users/ismarsuleimanov_wp3/site`) или изменился домен. А тема, скорее всего, самописная.

Почитайте, как правильно вносить изменения на сайт в таких условиях: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562). В вашем случае плагины бэкапа неприменимы, придётся пользоваться скриптом Database Search and Replace.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка исправлена.

**Решение:** Сама тема устарела и обновлений не было а wordpress обновленный, последняя версия, пришлось полностью заменять все старые вызовы типа: 
$this->WC_Widget на parent::__construct и много едругое.
Так же в некоторых плагинах наблюдались такие же проблемы.
В папке wp-include были найдены какие то левые файлы не относящиеся к wordpress.

Все удалил, изменил, заменил и все заработало.

Всем спасибо за помощь!